# I need to play audio file when microphone detects noise

Tags: applications

I have some pretty rare use case.
I've recorded audio file and I want to play it automatically
anytime when microphone detects any noise.

I assume it can be done using smartphone with Android with some app(s).

What's the best way to do it?

Just for the sake of example. Imagine I've recorded "Go away, we are home!" and put smartphone in dining room. The mic is working all the time, listening to noises and if someone breaks glass and gets inside a house, my record will automatically play and scare the thieves.

Thank you!